# Make a clickable object appear when I click on a different DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

See the image I've included. When you click on a row in the table (it won't be a table most likely, as each row will probably be a Dojo Widget), the 'pulldown shade' appears and is clickable. When the user clicks it, a new layer of content appears and the pulldown shade switches from 'Open' to 'Close'.

Can that all be done with CSS, meaning do a Hover:After type event, or am I going to have to use JS to make this happen? JS isn't an issue, just trying to confirm I'll have to use JS to make it happen.

[image]

Comment: You need to do this with a combo of JS/jQuery and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is required for the click event,

1 - you can show the additional content with hover

2 - then bind this to click ( *no point using hover as old IE does not work unless it is an anchor tag **`<a>`** * )

3 - you then can switch the text with js.

:)

**remember**

- css is for visual
- js is for behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS there is an option to use `:target` pseudo class (more on this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:target ), but I am not sure this will work well for in your case - you’d have to create separate element for each row, and it doesn’t seem wise.